# Infinitely linear torque with current in motor?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, magnetic-flux

I'm trying to find the maximum current my brushless DC motor can handle. If I can keep the coils and cabling cool (in a freezer right now), is there any other fundamental limit I may hit such as saturating a magnetic field?  I'm trying to plot an empirical Torque-Current curve where I measure torque with an oversized mass on a scale and a small pulley, but so far have not seen any tapering off of the torque.

Answer (score 4):

If you push enough current into the coils of a permanent magnet motor, then eventually you will demagnetise the field magnets. This is NOT GOOD for the motor. However, this current is usually fairly generously above the maximum normal running current, which is a thermal limit, and can be exceeded for short periods. But how much above?

With brushed DC motors, it's quite easy to get a figure for the safe maximum current, and that's the stall current when the rated voltage is applied.

With brushless DC, you'll need to dig through the specifications. A reputable manufacturer will tell you.

Answer (score 0):

BLDC motors vary in \$\omega L/R =\$ ratio  constant slightly for similar max RPM. At 0 RPM, the coil only has real resistance and the current rises to 10 or 12x rated load current or I.start=Imax * (10~12).

With water cooled engines this ratio is reduced since the rated power is increased by water cooling. I would expect this to out perform steady state what you were planning.

Saturation occurs with excess voltage, not current.

Comment: "Saturation occurs with excess voltage, not current." Please elaborate. I always thought it was the other way around.

Comment: Motors are designed not to saturated at no low or full load or dead start, so you only do that by raising the voltage above rated